# Why do confidence limits for fixed effects differ between lme and lmer in a simple linear mixed effects model

Tags: r, mixed-models

I'm trying to model a gaussian output with two fixed effects (treatment and sequence) and a single random effect patient. Patient is nested within sequence (different patients for every sequence, but patient is crossed with treatment (each patient gets every treatment). There are 4 treatments (`'Placebo', 'Low', 'Medium', 'High'`) and 6 sequences and two patients per sequence, so a total of 48 observations.

I tried using both lmer from the lme4 package and lme from the nlme package. The results agree regarding the point estimates and CI's for the treatment effect, and regarding the point estimates for the sequence effect, but differ regarding the CI's for the sequence effect. If anyone can help me understand why, I would much appreciate it. Nesting of patient within sequence is implicit by the fact that patient labels are unique across all sequences. Models are below.

```
mdl0 <- lmer(y ~ tx_ + seq_  + (1|pat), data = df);
mdl1 <- lme(y ~ tx_ + seq_, data = df, random = ~1|pat);
```

An example with randomly generated data is provided below.

```
library(nlme)
library(lme4)

tx <- c('Placebo', 'Low', 'Medium', 'High');
## 6 possible treatment sequences
seq <- 1:6;
## 2 patients nested in each sequence, so 12 patients altogether
pat <- 1:2;

## Treatment effect
tx.eff <- 0:length(tx)*0.5

## Error standard deviation
sig <- 0.2;

df <- merge(tx, seq);
names(df) <- c('tx_', 'seq_')
df <- merge(df, pat);
names(df)[3] <- 'pat'
df$pat <- paste0(LETTERS[df$seq_], df$pat);
df <- df[order(df$seq_),];

## Residuals
resid <- rnorm(nrow(df), 0, sig);
## Patient effect
pat.eff <- rnorm(length(unique(df$pat)));
## dependent variable = treatment effect + patient effect + residual
df$y <- tx.eff[match(tx, df$tx_)] + pat.eff[match(df$pat, unique(df$pat))] + resid;

df$tx_<- factor(df$tx_, levels = tx);
df$seq_<- factor(df$seq_);

## Nesting of patient within sequence is implicit by the fact that patient labels are unique across all sequences
mdl0 <- lmer(y ~ tx_ + seq_  + (1|pat), data = df);
mdl1 <- lme(y ~ tx_ + seq_, data = df, random = ~1|pat);

mdl0.CI <- confint(mdl0);
mdl1.CI <- intervals(mdl1);

## Extract the treatment effects for the lmer model. 
tx_effs <- c('tx_Low', 'tx_Medium', 'tx_High');
tx_effs0 <- mdl0.CI[tx_effs,];
## ... and repeat for the lme model
tx_effs1 <- mdl1.CI$fixed[tx_effs,-2]

## ... now look at the sequence effects
seq_effs <- grep('seq_', rownames(mdl0.CI), value = T);
seq_effs0 <- mdl0.CI[seq_effs,];

## ... and repeat for the lme model
seq_effs1 <- mdl1.CI$fixed[seq_effs,-2]

## Treatment effect CI's are the same for the lme and lmer models
tr_eff_difs <- tx_effs1 - tx_effs0;
## ... but sequence effects are not.
seq_eff_difs <- seq_effs0 - seq_effs1
```

Comment: Appreciate the example, but it is not reproducible: don't know what `sig` or `df` are so cannot generate the residuals, patterns, etc

Comment: At a guess I would say that perhaps the methods that each function uses is different. with `lmer` you can choose REML or ML

Comment: I suspect the difference lies not so much in the model fits but in the way `confint()` (for the lmer-fit) and `intervals()` (for the lme-fit) calculate the confidence intervals. Calculating CIs for mixed models is not trivial and different methods result in (slightly) different results, see for instance here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/117641/133735.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I experimented with REML and ML in  ````lme```` and indeed the sequence (````seq_````) CI's differ between the two, but unfortunately neither matches the ````lmer```` result. (````sig```` is just the residual standard deviation (sigma) and ````df```` is just the data frame used to store the dataset for modelling)